# Finding sum-of-square fractions in an aggregated dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

Let's say I have a simplified DataFrame that looks as such:

```
A  B  C
-------
9  6  8 
9  6  8
9  6  7
7  4  2
8  3  2
```

I want to `groupBy` columns `A` and `B`, and for each partition, I want to find the sum of the fractions of the *unique* values of C. So for example, when grouping by `A` and `B`, for values 9 and 6, respectively, my value would be (2/3)^2 + (1/3)^2. The 3 comes becomes there are 3 values in the partition, the 2 is from the number of 8's, and the 1 is from the number of 7's. And this should be done for each partition that is created by the `groupBy` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{pow, sum}

val w = Window.partitionBy("A", "B")

val tmp = pow(
  $"count" /             // numerator (see below)
  sum($"count").over(w), // denominator
2)

df
  .groupBy($"A", $"B", $"C").count  // Find numerators 
  .withColumn("_tmp", tmp) // Compute fractions
  .groupBy($"A", $"B").agg(sum($"_tmp").as("ssq")) // Compute totals
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with a DF that already had the `groupBy("A", "B")` called on it?

Comment: I guess to rephrase, I already perform a lot of transformations on this (using `groupBy` and `agg`) + `UDFs` for the calculations. For all of those, I need the original table data, not the aggregated data, so is there any way to do this during that specific `groupBy` statement?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean :) GroupBy is just a logical operation. If you have groups like this above you can use them but it won't change much in 1.6+ where aggregations are scheduled separately.

Comment: Essentially, I already do something like: `df.groupBy("A", "B").agg ( ... )`. So there's two issues with the solution you posted: (1) If I do the processing _before_ the mentioned `groupBy` statement, then the data is already transformed. (2) If I do it afterwards, then the data is already grouped, before I can do the new calculations. The only solution I can think of is doing both separately and perhaps joining the tables, though I am not too familiar with that. Does this make sense?

Comment: You can easily add `sum($"_tmp").as("ssq")` to the existing `agg` clause so the only possible problem is `.groupBy($"A", $"B", $"C").count`. It can be replaced by windowed equivalent if you need that but it is more expensive an trickier.

Comment: Okay, yeah this is precisely the issue I was running into before as there was no good way I could express this. I guess it would be way too expensive to do these separately and join the tables afterwards or append the column.

Comment: It solely depends on amount of data and levels. If lets `groupBy($"A", $"B").agg(sum($"_tmp").as("ssq"))` is small enough for broadcast join it should be perfectly acceptable but without precise example it is just guessing.

Comment: @zero323 I was facing similar issue. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @zero323 Do u ve any idea on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113765/value-filter-is-not-a-member-of-org-apache-spark-sql-groupeddata