# Spark: How to parse multiple json with List of arrays of Struct?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get avg of ratings of all JSON objects in a file. I loaded the file and converted to data frame but getting error while parsing for avg. 
Sample Request :

```
{
        "country": "France",
        "customerId": "France001",
        "visited": [
            {
                "placeName": "US",
                "rating": "2.3",
                "famousRest": "N/A",
                "placeId": "AVBS34"

            },
              {
                "placeName": "US",
                "rating": "3.3",
                "famousRest": "SeriousPie",
                "placeId": "VBSs34"

            },
              {
                "placeName": "Canada",
                "rating": "4.3",
                "famousRest": "TimHortons",
                "placeId": "AVBv4d"

            }        
    ]
}
```

so for this JSON, US avg rating will be  (2.3 + 3.3)/2  = 2.8

```
{
        "country": "Egypt",
        "customerId": "Egypt009",
        "visited": [
            {
                "placeName": "US",
                "rating": "1.3",
                "famousRest": "McDonald",
                "placeId": "Dedcf3"

            },
              {
                "placeName": "US",
                "rating": "3.3",
                "famousRest": "EagleNest",
                "placeId": "CDfet3"

            },


}

{
        "country": "Canada",
        "customerId": "Canada012",
        "visited": [
            {
                "placeName": "UK",
                "rating": "3.3",
                "famousRest": "N/A",
                "placeId": "XSdce2"

            },


    ]
}
```

for this avg for us= (3.3 +1.3)/2 = 2.3

so over all, the average rating will be : (2.8 + 2.3)/2 = 2.55  (only two requests have 'US' in their visited list)

My schema :

```
root
|-- country: string(nullable=true)
|-- customerId:string(nullable=true)
|-- visited: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |   |-- placeId: string (nullable = true)
|    |   |-- placeName: string (nullable = true) 
|    |   |-- famousRest: string (nullable = true)
|    |   |-- rating: string (nullable = true)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.jsonFile("temp.txt")
df.show()
```

so basically I need to get average of ratings where placeName = 'US' in say for eg. AVG_RATING = sum of rating in each JSON object where placeName is US / count of such visited entry and FINAL_VALUE = Sum of all AVG_RATING in each JSON object with placeName 'US' / count of all JSON objects with placeName = 'US' .

So far I tried :

```
 df.registerTempTable("people")
   sqlContext.sql("select avg(expResults.rank) from people LATERAL VIEW explode(visited)people AS expResults where expResults.placeName = 'US' ").collect().foreach(println)

    val result = df.select("*").where(array_contains (df("visited.placeName"), "US"));  - gives the list where visited array contains US. But I am not sure how do parse through list of structs.
```

Can some one tell me how do I do this ?

Comment: could you paste just one sample json for trying?

Comment: @WoodChopper updated with a sample json object

Comment: Did u find the solution for this?

Comment: @user3407267 No, trying many different options but no solution yet. Still stuck.

Comment: I don't understand why  `(2.3 + 3.3)/2 = 4.45` or  `(3.3 +1.3)/2 = 3.95`

Comment: @zero323: Hi, (2.3 + 3.3)/2 = 4.45 - if u see the json (1st one) - it has 3 requests but only 2(visited entries) has us as placeName.

Comment: @zero323: the  3 requests in the comment above just means total number of entries in the visited array.

Comment: I don't get it. 2.3 + 3.3 = 5.6, 5.6 / 2 = 2.8 != 4.25

Comment: @zero323  - Sorry for that  confusion. Its 2.8 only.

Comment: So `(3.3 +1.3)/2 = 2.3` and you want ` 2.55` as total?

Comment: @zero323 yeah the total will be 2.55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you want something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{avg, explode}

val result = df
  .withColumn("visit", explode($"visited"))    // Explode visits
  .groupBy($"customerId", $"visit.placeName")  // Group by using dot syntax
  .agg(avg($"visit.rating".cast("double")).alias("tmp"))
  .groupBy($"placeName").agg(avg($"tmp").alias("value"))
```

After that you can filter this for a country of your choice.

```
result.where($"placeName" === "US").show
// +---------+-----+
// |placeName|value|
// +---------+-----+
// |       US| 2.55|
// +---------+-----+
```

Less elegant approach is to use an UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

def userAverage(country: String) = udf((visits: Seq[Row]) => Try {
   val filtered = visits
     .filter(_.getAs[String]("placeName") == country)
     .map(_.getAs[String]("rating").toDouble)
   filtered.sum / filtered.size
}.toOption)

df.select(userAverage("US")($"visited").as("tmp")).na.drop.agg(avg("tmp"))
```

**Note**: This follows the decription provided in the question by computing average of averages which is different from the accepted answer. For simple average:

```
val result = df
  .select(explode($"visited").alias("visit"))
  .groupBy($"visit.placeName")
  .agg(avg($"visit.rating".cast("double")))
```

Comment: Well, you can try an UDF to avoid explode but in general Spark support for nested structures is fairly limited so I wouldn't expect impressive performance, especially with JSON.

Comment: Thank you for ur explanation. Can I add filter here ? like saying use the rating for us in avg calc only if it is above  3 (visited.rating)?

Comment: val result = df
  .withColumn("visit", explode($"visited")).filter($"visited.rating" > 3.0)   
  .groupBy($"customerId", $"visit.placeName")  
  .agg(avg($"visit.rating".cast("double")).alias("tmp"))
  .groupBy($"placeName").agg(avg($"tmp").alias("value"))

Comment: I used the above to filter the rating (include only those are > 3) Am I doing the correct approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Follows my solution to your problem.

```
val DF = sqlContext.jsonFile("sample.json")


DF.registerTempTable("temp")


sqlContext.sql("select place_and_rating.placeName as placeName, avg(place_and_rating.rating) as avg_rating from temp lateral view explode(visited) exploded_table as place_and_rating where place_and_rating.placeName='US' group by place_and_rating.placeName").show()
```

Comment: I am getting failure: ``union'' expected but identifier view found for ur solution. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: do I need to import anything ?

Comment: You don't need to import anything for this solution. jsonFile & resisterTempTable are inbuilt methods available for sqlContext and rest is just HQL.

Comment: What version of Spark are you using? And can you please post your code in the comments section?

Comment: spark 1.5.2 I created a json file with given structure. Used :sqlContext.sql("select place_and_rating.placeName as placeName, avg(place_and_rating.rating) as avg_rating from temp lateral view explode(visited) exploded_table as place_and_rating where place_and_rating.placeName='US' group by place_and_rating.placeName").show()

Comment: Did you register the dataframe as a temporary table?

Comment: @user3407267 I think u might need to add : import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)

Comment: @Rahul I tried ur query it works fine. To get include the visited.rating which are < 20 I just added : sqlContext.sql("select place_and_rating.placeName as placeName, avg(place_and_rating.rating) as avg_rating from temp lateral view explode(visited) exploded_table as place_and_rating where place_and_rating.placeName='US' and place_and_rating.rating < 20 group by place_and_rating.placeName").show()

Comment: @Rahul : Is that correct way to filter our the visited.rating

Comment: @Newbiee that's correct! The SQL method from sqlContext allows you to do pretty much everything you can do to a Hive table. Hence adding a filter with "and" clause is perfectly fine!

Comment: Regarding @user3407267 issue, if he is using spark-shell/pyspark, he dont need to explicitly add sqlContext/hiveContext class. Would you mind posting the detailed code and issue log for debugging